# Dash Streaming server prototype

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

While learning about live streaming I found not much of comprehensive info across the web. This field seems very proprietary and commercialized with lots of ill-described standards and protocols. But I have a plan to deeply understand the internals of live streaming and implement a prototype server. NGINX setup is not a way to rich this goal, all the guts are hidden inside a spooky C implementation. But, what it takes nowadays to implement its own live streaming server over DASH/HLS?

Do you know any guidelines about DASH/HLS live streaming server implementation? (preferably on Go/Python)
If not, can you briefly describe key components behind the live streaming server?

Comment: It would likely be a useful to look at an opensource streamer to get some ideas and see how people have approached it - e.g. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.orghttps://gstreamer.freedesktop.org. There are links to API documentation and developer documentation also

Answer (score 2):

Actually for DASH or HLS, the server is just a standard HTTP server... nothing more.

That's the whole purpose of DASH and HLS... to re-use existing HTTP-based infrastructure so that specialized streaming servers are not necessary.  An encoder takes audio/video and records segments (usually 4-8 seconds long) and writes them out as individual files.  It also writes out a manifest or playlist, which is essentially a list of URLs for those segments, along with some metadata indicating bitrate, codec, and what not.

The client makes a normal HTTP request for the playlist or manifest, and then makes normal HTTP requests to get the segments it wants.  The server doesn't have to know or care that it's serving audio/video segments, vs. any other binary resource.

Comment: Nice response. It might be worth adding that in most deployments of any size, specialised 'origin' servers are still used in practice. Usually, one of the key drivers is to have a single copy of the source video which is then re-packaged into HLS or DASH just in time, or on the fly, when it is requested. In practice these servers also provide extra functionality like just in time encryption, timed metadata, ad insertion logic etc.